# How to make single bundle using webpack 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack-2

I want to bundle my angular 2 project to a single file. Now when I'm bundling it using webpack 2, I'm having single main.bundle.js and many files like this: `0.hash.js`, `1.hash.js` and so on. How to tell to webpack 2 I want only main.bundle.js?